# Is there a way to connect to a Sphinx compilation process in order to get the (re)generated files on the fly?

Tags: python-sphinx

We use `Sphinx` for a large LaTeX FAQ, with over 1200 (`MyST` `Markdown`) source files which generates a static HTML website using CI/CD on a GitLab instance. We managed to reduce the compilation time to around :

- 4 minutes when all the HTML pages have to be (re)generated,
- 30 seconds when only one HTML page needs to be (re)generated.

We now need to apply a (`Perl`) script to all the (re)generated HTML pages. During the compilation of `Sphinx`, thanks to the `-vv` option in `sphinx-build`, we collect in a file (say `changed-source-files.txt`) the list of (the paths of) the HTML files (re)generated. So, when the compilation of `Sphinx` is complete, we apply our script to these modified files (collected in `changed-source-files.txt`) and only to these files.

The problem is this: when the 1200 pages have to be (re)generated, running this script after the end of the `Sphinx` compilation takes a long time, around 2 minutes.

So the question is: is there a way of 'connecting' our script to the `Sphinx` compilation in order to retrieve the modified files on the fly and, consequently, to run our script in parallel with the `Sphinx` compilation, which continues to run?